# "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method never called on iOS 10 devices

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios10, xcode8, didselectrowatindexpath

My current app is available on the store for several months now. This app contains several `UIListView`, using custom cells (each cell in its own `NIB`) and touching a cell was always functional.

Now, without any update of the app, it appears since *iOS 10* that touching a cell does not do anything, no event is triggered and neither `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` are called.

This only occurs on *iOS 10* devices, even after updating to *SWIFT 3*.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Did you check with XCode View Hierarchy debug tool https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html if there is no view blocking the touch? Did you check that the `UITableView` delegate is not nil?

Comment: Hi thanks. delegate is not null, I will try the debugger. But I don't see how it could be possible as the same code is running well on iOS 8 and 9.

Comment: By `UIListView` you mean the built-in `UITableView` or is it custom view?

Comment: Yes sorry, UITableView (my Android reflexes). By the way, my view hierarchy is ok, nothing blocks. I have a GADNativeContentAdView from DFP library, but it seems it does not have any effect : if I don't use it, it's still not ok.

Comment: I am learning swift now, so my apologies if my hypothesis doesn't make any sense. Didn't it become didSelectRowAt & willSelectRowAt now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. It seems to be a DFP lib behavior "incompatibility" issue. The DFP view I use to contain all cell's elements, cause sometimes it's displaying custom ad content. This view get user interactions, which is obvious in order to track ad clicks and get analytics, but in iOS 10 this prevent the cell to get any touch event : all is handle by DFP view. So the solution was simply to force `userInteractionsEnabled` to `false` when I display non ad content.